# Pandas - Build sequnce in the group while resetting and create new dataframe with summary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got some help in the past and was able to advance well. Now I have an additional need to create a summary dataset for the study. Please help me if you can.

This is my current Dataset:
import pandas as pd

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'three','three', 'two','two','two','two'],    
                    'pattern': ['A', 'B', '000', 'C', 'A', '000','D','A','C'],        
                    'date': ['11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022', '11/8/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/14/2022','11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022']})


m = df2['pattern'] == '000'
df2['result'] = (df2[~m].groupby(['patient', m.cumsum()])
                        .cumcount().add(1)
                        .reindex(df2.index, fill_value=0))

df2
```

From the above current Dataset, I like to create a summary dataset like shown below. Can you help me how extract the below summary dataset from the above dataset, please?

```
required_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'pattern': ['A,B', 'C,A','D,A,C'],   ### Pattern happend by Date
                    'patients': [1,1,1]})                             ### Total Number of unique patients

required_dataset
```

Comment: How do you compute `patients` to get `[2, 1, 1]` ?

Comment: sorry....that unique patients [1,1,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this:

```py
m = df2["pattern"] == "000"

summary_df = df2[~m].groupby("patient").agg(pattern = ("pattern", lambda x: ','.join(x)),
                                            patients = ("patient", "count")).reset_index()

summary_df
```

Prints:

```
    patient pattern   patients
0   one     A,B       2
1   three   C,A       2
2   two     D,A,C     3
```

The first `pattern` column concatenates all the patterns with `' ,'.join(x)`.
The second `patient` column counts the number of visits.

Granted, the `required_dataframe` you provided had different values in this one, but I guess you meant visits. If not, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Looks great. Is that possible to show only the last 2 columns? pattern & patients (unique) please?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html?highlight=agg#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg) :

```
out = (
        df2[~m].groupby("patient")
                    .agg(pattern= ("pattern", ",".join),
                         patients=("patient", "nunique"))
                    .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

  pattern  patients
0     A,B         1
1     C,A         1
2   D,A,C         1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. My dataset has 1000s of patients and this code helps me indeed.